# hash to json with out nested arrays in json

Tags: json, ruby

I am generating a hash out of three arrays and next trying to construct a json. I succeeded by json object has array.

```
require 'json'
A = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], [ "A1_xfactor", "A2_xfactor", "A3_xfactor"], ["A1_pull", "A2_pull", "A3_pull"]]

kl = { 'obj' => A[0].zip(A[1],A[2]).map { |k, v,l|  { 'f1' => k, 'f2' => v, 'xfactor' => l} }}.to_json


puts kl
```

Output

```
  {
    "obj": [{
        "f1": "A1",
        "f2": "A1_xfactor",
        "xfactor": "A1_pull"
    }, {
        "f1": "A2",
        "f2": "A2_xfactor",
        "xfactor": "A2_pull"
    }, {
        "f1": "A3",
        "f2": "A3_xfactor",
        "xfactor": "A3_pull"
    }]
}
```

Instead of array, I would like have it without an array and F1 has to come out as a separate object.

```
{
    "obj": {
        "A1": {
            "f2": "A1_xfactor",
            "xfactor": "A1_pull"
        },
        "A2": {
            "f2": "A2_xfactor",
            "xfactor": "A2_pull"
        },
        "A3": {
            "f2": "A3_xfactor",
            "xfactor": "A3_pull"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try reducing `A` by zipping each of its elements.

Then iterate over each array of arrays using `each_with_object`, for each element, yield its first element as `key`, the second as `f2` and the second/last element within the array as `factor`.

Assign the custom hash to the `key` (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`).

After that you can store it and use like `{ obj: result }`.

```
A.reduce(&:zip).each_with_object({}) do |((key, f2), factor), hash|
  hash[key] = { f2: f2, xfactor: factor }
end
# {"A1"=>{:f2=>"A1_xfactor", :xfactor=>"A1_pull"},
#  "A2"=>{:f2=>"A2_xfactor", :xfactor=>"A2_pull"},
#  "A3"=>{:f2=>"A3_xfactor", :xfactor=>"A3_pull"}}
```

Comment: `A.reduce(&:zip)`: I'll remember that.